# iso 8583 problem cannot receive response properly

Tags: iso, iso8583

I am new to ISO-8583, there is an error Required 912 but just got 408 bytes bit-60 and tried to search for this problem and I found it, it's because of the response from host has been cut off. Can anyone give me advice about this?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a lot of relevant information that would be necessary to provide help:
- What dialect of 8583 are you using? I.e. what are you trying to connect to?
- What software are you using to generate and send messages? Can you provide relevant pieces of code?
- What bytes are you sending? What bytes are you receiving?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811173/iso-8583-send-request-but-cannot-get-full-response-from-server-how-can-i-fix-th
you can come to this link i allready asked this problem and i have an example code there thanks